# how to compile all files in a given directory with mingw-w64 (Debian[kali Linux])

Tags: c++, compilation, debian, mingw-w64, mingw32

I am following a textbook guide and the guy uses the following command on a directory using mingw32
and a Kali Linux system

```
 i586-mingw32msvc-c++ Hyperion-1.0/Src/Crypter/*.cpp -o hyperion.exe
```

i am using mingw-w64 with the same system and tried the following command

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter/*.cpp -o hyperion.exe
```

and gets the following error

> cc1plus: fatal error: Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter/*.cpp: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

i tried looking for answers in existing forums but the only ones that talked about it where on windows.

Comment: `Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter` probably is not relative to the current folder you type that command from.

Comment: i am working from the download folder in the terminal and in the same folder Hyperion-2.3.1 is located, also tried using the whole /home/... path

Answer (score 1):

so i fixed it
first of all i tried making a exe file out of this dir using mingw-64w
in the text book the guy used .cpp but since i had a newer version of the project it was fully written in .c so that had to change, then i got another error in compilation that some .h file is missing so i went to the devs repo and downloaded the project from their insted of their website and it worked once i used:

> x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hyperion-kali-master/Src/Crypter/*.c -o hyperion.exe

Comment: Thaks a lot for this reply

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would expect some build system to be used (Autoconf+Make, CMake, Meson), but if not you can do it like this from the shell:

```bash
for F in Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter/*.cpp; do
 echo CXX $F
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc $F -o $F.o || break
done
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o hyperion.exe Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter/*.o
```